# Error and Crash when using the Core Data to create a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I try to use Core Data to make a `UITableView`, but I come across a crash when I run it:

```
014-07-29 10:13:12.443 TableAndCoreData[797:60b] -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f319a0
2014-07-29 10:13:12.446 TableAndCoreData[797:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f319a0'
```

I generally check it and I guess it might be the problem of the creating the `managedObjectContext`. Does any one have some idea to help me to fix this problem?

```
@interface DetailViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ageTextField;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

// Set NSManagedObjectContext
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedOjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedOjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self save];
}

- (void)save
{
    // Get ManagedObjectContext
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedOjectContext];

    // Create a ManagedObject
    NSManagedObject *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // Set value for the attributes of the entity
    [aPerson setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [aPerson setValue:self.ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];

    // Check the error
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't save due to %@%@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Besides, I am trying another way to create `UITableView` using Core Data:

```
 - (void) save
{
    // Create UIManagedDocument
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]firstObject];
    NSString *documentName = @"Model";
    NSURL *url = [documentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
                    // Get a ManagedObjectContext
                    NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;

                    // Set managed object (entity)
                    NSManagedObject *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                    // Set value for the attribute (which are "name" and "age") of the entity
                    [aPerson setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
                    [aPerson setValue:self.ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];

                    // Check whether there is an error
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't save due to %@%@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                    }

                    // Close the window
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"couldn't open document at %@", url);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
                    // Get a ManagedObjectContext
                    NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;

                    // Set managed object (entity)
                    NSManagedObject *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                    // Set value for the attribute (which are "name" and "age") of the entity
                    [aPerson setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
                    [aPerson setValue:self.ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];

                    // Check whether there is an error
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't save due to %@%@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                    }

                    // Close the window
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"couldn't open document at %@", url);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

However, it just couldn't find the `UIManagedDocument`. I really wonder the reason why I should create a `UIManagedDocument` and the document name I should name it.

Comment: This bit of code doesn't look pretty: `id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedOjectContext];
    }`

Comment: Tips: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord + https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator Ease Core Data development by a lot !

Comment: Yes. And I think this might be where I come across the problem. I just copy this piece of code from tutorials.

Comment: Troop231 is right, you should NEVER use id unless you are forced to.   Your compiler will probably gives you an answer to your question if you use stronger typing.

Comment: Copy and pasting tutorial code generally will introduce issues. Also, normal way of casting the app delegate: `#import "AppDelegate.h" AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: To be clear, you do not use Core Data to make a `UITableView`, you (generally) create a custom subclass of `UITableViewController` to create and configure a `UITableView`. You use Core Data to feed data to your table view controller data source methods, such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your *crash* does not have anything to do with Core Data.

Change this:
`[delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]`

to:
`[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]`

The crash was happening because you were sending the message `managedObjectContext` to the application delegate object, which does not respond to that message. It was being sent because where you meant to check to see if it responds to that message with `respondsToSelector:`, you had `performSelector` instead. Your application delegate object still needs to implement `managedObjectContext` for your code to be functional, but the portions you have posted should no longer crash as you describe.

In general you want to avoid calling a method on the application delegate this way. It's preferred to pass a value like this from the application delegate into the root view controller at startup, and it's passed along to the next view controller and the next.

There is a slightly outdated, but still relevant section of the [Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW2) that discusses this:

> A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a global object such as the application delegate—this makes the application architecture rigid. Neither should a view controller create a context for its own use (unless it’s a nested context).

...as well as the [iOS 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html):

> Nested contexts make it more important than ever that you adopt the “pass the baton” approach of accessing a context (by passing a context from one view controller to the next) rather than retrieving it directly from the application delegate.

Comment: @qyellish Thanks so much! However, although I changed like what you said, it still crashed.